# How can I sort variables into groups of three such that the average similarity is the highest possible?

Tags: matrices, average, sorting

I have a spreadsheet in which the leftmost column and topmost row contain 12 names, and the values in the cells inside represent the similarity (on a scale of -1 to 1) between the names in the column and the row.

Image: 
[image]

My goal is to sort the names into three groups of four such that the average similarity between the names in each group is as high as possible. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic case of similarity clustering, where you must be explicit about what you mean by "similarity."  The simplest technique is $k$-means clustering under constraints.  A web search will bring up the explicit algorithms.

Comment: K-means needs *coordinates*, not similarities. Because it computes the means as cluster centers - that needs coordinates not similarities.